# Безопасность установки apk

Tags: android, безопасность, apk

Есть ли в плане безопасности разница, из какого источника устанавливается приложение - из Google Play или самостоятельным apk-файлом?

В андроиде есть есть разрешений для приложений, которая по идее должна защищать от нежелательных действий. Есть ли какой-то неявно выдаваемый набор разрешений при установке apk или что-то ещё делающее такую установку менее безопасной? Почему везде пишут, что ставить apk не из магазина крайне нежелательно?

Comment: В apk может быть зашит вредоносный код. В маркете этот шанс довольно низок.

Comment: В маркете гугл может отозвать сертификат если программа оказалась "плохой", и оштрафовать нарушителей. А apk может содержать почти что угодно. Лично моё мнение - если apk не содержит галочек "сеть" и других опасных галочек, например это тупо будильник без доступа к диску флешке сети хранилищам - то его можно ставить. Но видимо что бы не обьяснять пользователям чем опасный apk отличается от безопасного - решили просто назвать все опасными.

Comment: @Battrip, что подразумевается под вредоносным кодом? Какой-то способ обхода системы разрешений? Или просто что прога в рамках своих разрешений может делать что угодно?

Comment: @nick_n_a, а если это телеграм, который собираются перестать распространять через Google Play?

Comment: @nick_n_a, кстати, что ты имел в виду под сетью? Звонки или интернет? Права на интернет ведь даются по умолчанию, как и ряд других прав (кстати, не знаю, каких именно), считающихся безопасными.

Comment: Любое ПО на андроиде будет действовать в рамках системы разрешений. Но имея, например, доступ к звонкам и смс, приложение может только получать некоторые события (двухфакторной авторизации для самого приложения, например), а может читать и отсылать на свой сервер вообще всю инфу. Гугл плей забанит за второе, а в иных источниках это кот в мешке.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, но разрешение на доступ к звонкам и смс я всё равно должен ему сам выдать? Неявно в момент установки оно получит ровно столько же разрешений, сколько получают обычные приложения из магазина?

Comment: Да, разрешение приложение все равно спросит и без него ничего не сделает. Если приложение никаких опасных разрешений не спрашивает - можно ставить спокойно. Вроде бы иногда всплывают случаи, что кто-то как-то обошел разрешение, но это чаще всего группы по исследованию безопасности, а не реальные хакеры-зловреды. В жизни проще соц инженерией разрешение получить, чем технически его обойти.